# using _set_se_translator and compilation flags

Tags: c++, winapi, msvcrt, crt

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states that "You must use /EHa when using _set_se_translator.".
My question is: should /EHa be used for all files in project/ all files in project that catch exceptions or just in the file that calls _set_se_translator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it not just for functions that *catch* exceptions, but also functions that throw and propagate them. The actual call to `_set_se_translator` itself probably doesn't need to be compiled with /Eha, but why be inconsistent?

Comment: as far as I have read using /Eha involves security issues and it is not good practice. And may result in a less performant image because the compiler will not optimize a try block as aggressively, even if the compiler does not see a throw.

Comment: Security issues? Don't think so. It _is_ less performent, yes. You've massively increased the number of instructions that can cause C++ exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: do you know how less efficient it is ? Maybe I should use SEH and convert exceptions myself.

Comment: Doesn't matter a whole lot in reasonable code (i.e. not throwing thousands of exceptions per second).

Answer (score 2):

After checking I must disagree with what has been said before about all instances needed to be compiled with /EHa. I made a small program with:

- crashing code

  ```
    __declspec(dllexport) void crashMe()  {    *((int*)0)=0;  }
  ```

in a DLL compiled without any exception handling at all

- calling code elsewhere in a try/catch

Then

- Unless the calling code is compiled with /EHa the program will crash
- Without `_set_se_translator` the exception can only be caught in `catch(...)`

Comment: thanks for the investigation ! The OP might have been in the same situation: using Boost.Test with an already compiled library, and I can enable /EHa only for the test file object